# How do we show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n \log (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Which criterion do we use to show the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n \log (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}$$ ?

Do we maybe use that $\log (n+1)<n$ and so we get $\frac{n\log (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}<\frac{n^2}{1+n^3x^2}$ ?

Since $1+n^3x^2>n^3x^2$ we get $$\frac{n\log (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}<\frac{n^2}{n^3x^2}=\frac{1}{nx^2}$$ But this one diverges, right?

So do we have to find an other uppoer bound? Or do we use an other criterion?

Comment: Instead of $\log(n+1)<n$ we may use e.g. $\log(n+1)<\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that $\log (n+1) \leqslant n^\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$ so you have estimation

$$\frac{n\log (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}<\frac{n^{1+\alpha}}{n^3x^2}=\frac{1}{n^{2-\alpha}x^2}$$

**Addition.**

As in comments arise question about continuity and differentiability, then let me say, that here key is domain with respect we are speaking. Function $f_n(x)=\frac{n\ln (n+1)}{1+n^3x^2}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (for simplicity I considering $\ln$). Same with $f'_n(x)=-\frac{2n^4x \ln (1+n)}{(1+n^3x^2)^2}$. Suppose we take any $x_0>0$, then exists $x_0 \gt a \gt 0$ such that $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and using same technique  as above gives us uniform convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f'_n(x)$ on $[a,b]$, so differentiability of $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ (so continuity) in $x_0$.

Comment: Ahh I see!! So let $f(x)$ be the result of the original sum. To check the continuity and differentiability of $f$ do we have to check fora specific $n$ the continuity and the differentiability? Ordowe have to calculate the formula for $f$ ?

Comment: Wrote addition.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in comments, you can use a better bound for the logarithm:

$$
\dfrac{n \log(n+1)}{1+n^3 x^2} \leq \frac{n \sqrt{n}}{n^3 x^2}= \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$

which now yields a convergent series.

Comment: Ahh I see!! So let $f(x)$ be the result of the original sum. To check the continuity and differentiability of $f$ do we have to check fora specific $n$ the continuity and the differentiability? Ordowe have to calculate the formula for $f$ ?

Comment: If you want to differentiate and relate the series of $f$ and $f'$, what you need to address is uniform convergence. The bounds proposed in the answers, without any further comment, only give you pointwise convergence.

Comment: So to check continuity and differentiability of $f$ do we have to check uniform convergence? Or have I understood your comment wrong?

Comment: We have that $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (-\frac{n^4\log (n+1)2x}{(1+n^3x^2)^2}\right )$$ right? So since we can calculate the derivative, $f$ is differentiable and so also continuous. Is that correct? Or am I confusing the meanings?

Comment: @MaryStar In general, you cannot exchange the sum and the derivative, i.e. you can have $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g_n(x)$, but $f'(x)$ not existing or not being equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g'_n(x)$. Under uniform convergence, all works fine.

Comment: But how do we show uniform convergence in such functions related with sum?

Comment: Loosely speaking, when a series of differentiable functions $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to some $f(x)$, the limit $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f'_n(x)$.

Comment: We have that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ pointwise. Then $\sup f_n(x)=f_n(0)$ since $f_n$ is decreasing, right?

Comment: Ah no... we look at the absolute value,so the supremum is 0 and so we have uniform convergence